# Doubt about energy conditions: the Time-like Convergence Condition

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics

First of all, consider a congruence of smooth time-like geodesics parametrized by proper time $\tau$. So, a tangent vector to a time-like geodesic is indeed a four-velocity up to a factor constant; then a vector field $\xi^{a}$ necessarily must satisfy the normalization condition (using geometrized units $G=c=1$):

$$g_{ab}\xi^{a}\xi^{b}=\xi^{a}\xi_{a} = -1$$

Also, define the following tensor field:

$$B_{ab} = \nabla_{b}\xi_{a}$$

where $\nabla_{b}$ are the components of covariant derivative; moreover define the spatial metric tensor field:

$$h_{ab} = g_{ab}+\xi_{a}\xi_{b}$$

Consider, then, the Raychaudhuri's  equation:

$$\xi^{c}\nabla_{c}\theta = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\theta = -\frac{1}{3}\theta^{2} - \sigma_{ab}\sigma^{ab} + \omega_{ab}\omega^{ab} - R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d}  \tag{1}$$

Where $\theta$ is the expansion scalar field which measures the average expansion of nearby surrounding geodesics; it's given by:

$$\theta = B^{ab}h_{ab}$$

the tensor field components $\sigma_{ab}$ are called shear tensor field; it's given by:

$$\sigma_{ab} = B_{(ab)} - \frac{1}{3}\theta h_{ab}$$

where $B_{(ab)}$ is a symmetric part of tensor field components $B_{ab}$ or symmetrization operation.

the tensor field components $\omega_{ab}$ are called twist or vorticity tensor field; it's given by:

$$\omega_{ab} = B_{[ab]}$$

where $B_{[ab]}$ is a antisymmetric part of tensor field components $B_{ab}$ or antisymmetrization operation.

$$* * *$$

So, from equation $(1)$, we want to analyse one term of right-hand side:

$$R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d}$$

Then, with a purely mathematical manipulation, we can use the Einstein Field Equations (EFE):

$$R_{cd} = 8\pi\Big (T_{cd} - \frac{1}{2}g_{cd}T\Big)$$

to reach :

$$R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} = \Big[ 8\pi\Big (T_{cd} - \frac{1}{2}g_{cd}T\Big) \Big] \xi^{c}\xi^{d} = 8\pi\Big (T_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} - \frac{1}{2}g_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} T\Big)= 8\pi\Big (T_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} + \frac{1}{2}T\Big) \tag{2}$$

From (2) equation, we have a scalar field quantity:

$$T_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \tag{3}$$

Which represents the local energy density of matter measured by an observer whose 4-velocity is  $\xi^{a}$. Moreover, the equation $(3)$ have a connection to physical world (i.e. to maintain the physical character of non-empty solution of EFE) by a hypotesis that classical matter must have a nonnegative energy density like:

$$T_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \geq 0 \tag{4}$$

My question is about the physical meaning of the "geometrical point" of the ricci term of Raychaudhuri's equation. I mean, when I look to the quantity $R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d}$, which seems to me to be just a mathematical link -throught EFE- to reach the equation $(3)$, I'm not finding a physical interpretation. 
Following the same path of interpretation of equation $(3)$, I would say then that $R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d}$ is the local curvature measured by a observer whose 4-velocity is $\xi^{a}$. I suspect that this is a wrong interpretation.

Furthermore, we can see that with the condition of equation $(4)$, we have also another (more general) condition:

$$R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \geq 0 \tag{5}$$

My question is: what are the physical interpretations of both $R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d}$ and $R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \geq 0$ ?

> Obs:
>   $R_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \geq 0$ and $T_{cd}\xi^{c}\xi^{d} \geq 0$ are called, respectively, *Time-like Convergence Condition* and *Weak Energy Condition*

Edit:----------------

From a restrict perspective, the theory of surfaces gives us a relation:

$$R_{ab} = K g_{ab} \tag{6}$$

Where $K$ is the Gaussian Curvature.

So if we plug this result into $R_{ab}\xi^{a}\xi^{b}$ we get:

$$R_{ab}\xi^{a}\xi^{b}\geq 0 \iff (K g_{ab})\xi^{a}\xi^{b}\geq 0 \iff K\xi_{a}\xi^{b}\geq 0 \iff -K \geq 0 $$

---

References

WALD.R., **General Relativity**. Chicago University Press. pages 211-219. Chicago, 1984

LOBO.F.S.N., **Fundamental Theories of Phyisics: Wormholes, Warp Drives and Energy Conditions**. Springer. pages 193-196.vol 186. Switzerland. 2017.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor (For equation (6) in "Special Cases")